# Passing Array to execute() function , PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, prepare

I am trying to study PHP PDO. I just created a function for inserting some data to database. But it gave me some error and data could not inserted.

Here is my code in action.php page

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `details` (`name`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES(?,?, ?)";
$params = array($name, $email, $pass);
$result = $connect -> query($query, $params);
```

this is the code in config.php

```
public function query($query, $params){
    $stmt = self::$db->prepare($query);
    $this -> result = $stmt -> execute($params);
    self::$db = NULL;
    return $this -> result;
}
```

this returns me the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer' in E:\wamp\www\test\pdo_test\action.php on line 14
```

I am just a beginer in this area. An another code works for me and inserted data. Which is

Action.php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `details` (`name`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$pass')";
$result = $connect ->query($query);
```

config.php

```
public function query($query){
$this->result = self::$db->query($query);
self::$db = NULL;
return $this -> result;
}
```

I am trying to convert this using `prepare()` and `execute()`. Someone please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you this approach, https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper
Which I wrote bearing in mind your exact case.

- thanks to execute returning self, it will make your query() function unnecessary
- thanks to singleton implementation, it will save you from many connection mistakes, such as `self::$db = NULL;`

While your code will remain the same clean and concise:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `details` (`name`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES(?,?, ?)";
$params = array($name, $email, $pass);
$result = DB::prepare($query)->execute($params);
```

As of your particular problem in the question, most likely $connection contains PDO instance instead of your own class instance, which error message clearly suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the changes didn't made any effect. It still shows the error as the above. I can't understand what is happening

Comment: *What* changes you are talking about?

Comment: Do you *really* take an answer as a source of code that have to be directly copy-pasted in your file?

Comment: 'public function query($query, $params){
  $this->result = self::$db->prepare($query)->execute($params);
  self::$db = NULL;
  return $this -> result;
 }' I changed code like this

Comment: I see. I've no more questions.

Comment: I didn't copy paste.. Just understand what you gave and just tried to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54428/discussion-between-arun-and-your-common-sense).